# Preflight, or CORS error, on every request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I've been struggling with CORS for a substantial amount of time, and still no closer to a full understanding.

My simplest example is using Wunderlist API -

Using the below code:

```
 var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/lists",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "x-client-id": "{ID}",
    "x-access-token": "{TOKEN}",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "data": "{\n\t\"revision\": 1,\n\t\"completed\": true\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Within Postman/Fiddler will return results. However, throwing it onto a basic site, or Codepen will either return a `405`, a `Pre-flight Warning` or an `Invalid Request`

I've loosely come to the understanding that you allow it within your server side, but I have to assume that not every single site out there allows for Postman etc to connect, nor for every vendor I sign up with it allow my domain.

How is it you work on bypassing the CORS Compliance within an API Call then? I've tried a lot of things I've read, including crossDomain, Cross-Origin Header, etc and always get same result.

Any insight?

Comment: GET never has preflight restrictions. POST, however, does.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - incorrect - custom headers trigger preflight

Comment: @JaromandaX please cite a spec that dictates this, because I am not aware of that restriction, and would like to see an authoritative link that confirms your claim.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - is MDN authoritative enough? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: As a mozilla employee: you bet!

Comment: Did you find the solution for the wunderlist api?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason it's being flagged for preflight is the extra headers you are sending. `GET` requests do not have to use a preflight request unless you are passing *custom* headers. You have two options:

1. The simplest solution is to remove the custom headers you are attempting to send, and the request should no longer get flagged as requiring CORS preflight.
2. If you are hosting the server code, you can check the incoming request (server-side) to see if it has request method `OPTIONS`. If so, you know this is the preflight and should respond with a response that tells the client what headers are acceptable. To allow all custom headers, the preflight response should contain a `'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*'` response header.

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Per https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/concepts/authorization you have to register your application for it to be able to talk to them. Somewhere in that process they may automatically start sending preflight requests for your domain or allow you to set the headers.

Comment: Assuming wunderlist supports CORS requests at all

Comment: @JaromandaX - If they require an `x-access-token` header, and expect their api to be usable, they should support CORS.

Comment: still an assumption :p

Comment: @cchamberlain Appreciate the link. It's actually being referenced to bounce back to my localhost:8080 source, which is what's being rejected. I've modified the base, but this seems like what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Might be they don't trust localhost. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Did you find the solution for the wunderlist api?

Comment: What I learned from this answer is the preflight is a check sent by the browser based on the request you're trying to make before it's sent. So if it fails you should look at the request you're making and change it to what the server allows. I removed a header in my request that wasn't allowed and the request completed. (Hi future me!)

Comment: For me to fix the preflight error I had to use Access-Control-Allow-Headers instead of Access-Control-Request-Headers in preflight response.