# axios API call does not fired

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a component that calls api and returns data, url is like this: https://myapi/CLASS_NBR. But right now the api does not get fired and it returns null. I checked the browser network status, there is not api call. Any idea?  My code is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class CourseDetail2 extends Component {
  state = {
    CLASS_NBR: this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR,
    course: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { CLASS_NBR } = this.state;
    this.runSearch();
  }

  runSearch = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `api/${this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR}`
    );
    this.setState({ course: response.data });
  };
  render() {
    const course = this.state.course; //null here

    return (
      <div>
        Course Detail: CLASS NBR {this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR} 
        ////this information is passed in through react-router Link 
        {course.SUBJECT} //null 
         CATALOGNO:{course.CATALOG_NBR}//null
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CourseDetail2;
```

Comment: How do you use your `CourseDetail2`? Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: It is called by clicking on a link from CourseList2.js  <Link  to={{ pathname: 'course/'+course.ID}}
                            
                            key={course.ID}>
                            View More
                        </Link>

Comment: So, another way to ask this question is, when user types https://myurl/ID, it makes axios api call to get object details information and displays it in the CourseDetail2.js component. How to trigger the api call?

Comment: Does the API get called with componentDidMount at least?

Comment: no. do I need a click event handler?

Comment: When you refresh the page, componentDidMount should get called after the component mounts. Try putting a console.log('componentDidMount') there and see if the message is printed out in the console. To answer your question, if you want runSearch to be called somewhere else, then yes, you would need to add a onClick={this.runSearch} attribute to your component.

Comment: The code as you have it should make an api call on mount. There are two reasons I can think of why it wouldn't get called: `this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR` is undefined and your api urls are incorrect. That's why I'm asking if you have any errors in console.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is here. If I refresh the URL, the API gets called. But if I click on the  <Link to={{ pathname: 'course/'+course.ID}} key={course.ID}> View More </Link> to navigate from CourseList2 to CourseDetail2 component, the API does not get called. How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @user788448 Did your issue get solved? I recently experienced the same problem. I am using `useEffect()` instead of `componentDidMount()`. However, it appears that through clicking on `URLs`, the `useEffect()` is fired, but not the `axios` one.

Answer (score 0):

Looked through many answers and findings, it appears the problem is likely due to the one of the below issues at the backend, which might happen independently or concurrently:

1. Preflight is not enabled across the `express` backend, use the below code after `app.use(cors())`:

```
app.options('*', cors());
```

2. The Success Status `204` is being choked on some legacy browsers, if setting options across different ports are acceptable, try the below codes:

```
const corsOptions = {
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

3. There are previous ports that did not return a response and thus is `pending` on the network. Large numbers of `pending` requests could prevent proper functioning of `axios`:

```
res.json('anything that suits your needs.');
// or
res.send('anything that suits your needs.');
```

Hope this answer could solve the problem for new-comers.

---

Appendix (no applied orders):

1. [Axios Post request for login is showing pending status?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903677/14499516)
2. [what does app.use(cors()) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46024491/14499516)
3. [Preflight, or CORS error, on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253321/14499516)
4. [AXIOS Post stay on PENDING in my REACT application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62149777/14499516)
5. [Axios post stay on pending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577213/14499516)