# AXIOS Post stay on PENDING in my REACT application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form

> Below is the Redux Action code that will be dispatched whenever **onSubmit** of Create
>   / Updating a profile:

I am using **AXIOS** lib for making the below **POST** calls to the backend - **MongoDB**.

```
const res = await axios.post(
      '/api/profile',
      formData,                 // Body
      config                    // Headers
    );
```

On my React application, the above lines of code works fine for **Create** but for the **Update**, it isn't returning anything and in the Networks Tab on Chrome Dev Tools, the status is **Pending**. Can someone help me understand where I would have made a mistake?

> Both the Create/Update calls worked fine when I did the **POST** request using
>   **Postman** with the same Headers and Payload data.

**Below is the Full code:**

```
// Create/Update Profile
export const createProfile = (formData, history, edit = false) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    debugger;
    const res = await axios.post(
      '/api/profile',
      formData,
      config
    );
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert(edit ? 'Profile Updated' : 'Profile Created'), 'success');

    if (!edit) {
      history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const errors = error.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: from your headers, it looks like you are specifying that body is going to be application/json, whereas you are sending data to api in string format

Comment: does your endpoint for updating and creating profile is same in the api? POST /api/profile ?

Comment: Take a look at your API endpoint in the backend and see what you are doing with the data received. Are you updating the same way as you are creating ? Are there any errors ? Are there any unresolved callbacks ? Without analyzing changes to your backend, you wouldn't be able to resolve data on the front.

Comment: @RahulPillai he said api is working fine if use by postman.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have made a single endpoint for Create/Update Profile and this is determined by the edit parameter in the function call.

Comment: @RahulPillai The Same works fine when used on Postman using the same Payload Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, My Bad!

I had some issue on the API endpoint, 
I was checking **if(formData.Skills)** and by mistake, I closed the *curly braces* at the wrong place after **catch** block and so the status was in **Pending** as there isn't any data returned.

Sorry, Guys!

Thank you all for your solutions, It helped me too. Have a lovely day!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your data sending way.

You are selecting `content-type: application/json` in headers whereas you are sending data in string.

Solution:

If your formData variable is an instance of class FormData then change your headers content-type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If your formData is a simple object then do not use JSON.stringify in axios.post method.

Also update your axios request:

```
const res = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:5000/api/profile',
      formData,
      config
    );
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I made the formData in JSON format and still the same issue.

Comment: can you see the network and tell me the url your frontend app is hitting?

Comment: Backend Runs on the port: 5000