# Axios Post request for login is showing pending status?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

This is MERN project. I'm trying to solve this problem. which contains basic form validation and login sends request to the database. now everything works good except "Axios post request for login page" Because the request showing status pending(204) and initiator is Preflight. Even the data that i'm sending through frontend(which is userid and password) is getting properly at the backend(nodeJS files index.js). Here i'll share the details of the code for more details.

Frontend Reactjs file (Login.js)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './login.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {

    const [user,setUser] = useState({
        Userid: "",
        Password: ""
    });

    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setUser({
            ...user,
            [name]:value
        })
    }
    console.log("This is Frontend:-",user);
    const login = () => {
         axios.post("http://localhost:8000/login",user)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="login">
            {console.log("USER",user)}
            <h1>TIMESHEET</h1>
            <h2>LOG IN</h2>
            <input type="text" name="Userid" value={user.Userid} placeholder="Enter UserID" onChange={handleChange} />
            <input type="password" name="Password" value={user.Password} placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={handleChange} />
            <div className="button" onClick={login}>Log In</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Backend Node file (Index.js)

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
// require('./model/userSchema');

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); 
app.options('*', cors()); // this enables preflight
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
require('./db/conn')

// const User = require('./model/userSchema');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Userid:String,
    Password:String,
    reEnterPassword:String
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

//Routes
app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
    const { Userid, Password } = req.body;
    console.log("Requested body",req.body);
    // console.log("pass:-",Password);
    User.findOne({Userid}), (err,user) =>{ 
                  
        if(user){
            if(Password === user.Password){
                res.status(200).json({message:"Login Successfull", user: user});
            }else{
                res.status(400).json({message:"Login Un-Successfull"});
            }
        }else{
           res.status(403).json({message:"User not Registered"}) 
        }
    }
})
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
   console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(res.data)` print?

Comment: where did i write console.log(res.data) please correct me if i'm wrong. And if it is then it is for just checking what data is present in variable. please ignore that console.log part and tell me where i'm getting to wrong to write this code

Answer (score 2):

Which version of express are you using in your project?

Place the CORS above parsing like below,

```
app.use(cors()); 
app.options('*', cors()); // this enables preflight
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

The above should do it if not add/try the below,

```
User.findOne({Userid}), (err,user) =>{ 
                  
        if(user){
            if(Password === user.Password){
                res.status(200).json({message:"Login Successfull", user: user});
               
            }else{
                res.status(400).json({message:"Login Un-Successfull"});
                
            }
        }else{
           res.status(403).json({message:"User not Registered"}) 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Version for "express": "^4.17.1". Thanks for helping me but still doesn't work for me. I'll edit what i have edited in the code as per your correction.

Comment: I think issue is occurring at frontend file login.js

Comment: I have also mention proxy address in package.json file of React. Most of the peoples do that to prevent CORS errors and avoiding pending requests but still doesn't work... :(